# TCP and HASH verification

Tags: node.js, flash, networking, tcp, air

I'm sending files over TCP using Nodejs and Adobe AIR, but when it comes to mobile devices, the hash becomes very slow in Actionscript.

My question is: do I really need to verify the hash of files after the transmission, or the TCP protocol ensures the integrity?

Thanks!

Comment: TCP ensures in-order delivery and integrity of the data it is asked to transfer. That doesn't mean that the data passed by the peer to TCP was valid in the first place.

Comment: @Asblarf If I'm sure that the data is valid, is it ok not to verify the hash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on exactly how you're sending the file, the receiver may not be able to know definitively that it received the entire file.  There are circumstances where a connection may be severed before the file is completely received.  Verifying the checksum (hash) of a file should ensure the entire file has been received.

Comment: I don't see how the connection can be severed without the receiver knowing about it. He will either get a read timeout, if he uses one, or an exception, or a valid end of stream. If and only if he gets a valid end of stream, the entire file was received.

Comment: Most TCP socket implementations merely indicate that the connection has closed (often by returning 0 bytes on the next `read()`).  Unless the receiver knows that there should be more data, it can't tell the difference between an early close and a normal one.  This is exactly the reason that HTTP includes the `Content-Length` header in responses and in `POST` requests.

Comment: I understand that the connection can lost some packets, making the entire file invalid if I just not verify if all data was transmited. Isn't better and faster just send a Content-Length in the start of the transmission?

Comment: @Formiga Losing packets in the middle won't hurt - you're using TCP, the sender  and receiver will cooperate to ensure that either all packets are received or that the connection is closed.  And yes, something like HTTP's `Content-Length` header helps - that's why HTTP has it.  But you asked about TCP, not HTTP, and TCP doesn't have anything like an "expected data size".